# What is the make of this 1940s faucet?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, faucet, bathtub, plumbing-fixture

Can anyone identify this tap stem?

[image: photo of tap stem]

[image: photo of tap stem with tap]

Comment: The best way is to take it to a plumbing store and they will match it for you.  Big box stores are iffy if they even know what it is.

Comment: Indeed, you want a local store (or small local chain) that likely was around when your house was built. Being staffed by somebody who looks like they may have helped build it is a bonus.